# Confusion definitions for the partition of an interval

Tags: real-analysis, definition, set-partition

The two following definitions appear in the literature.

**Definition 1.** A partition of a set $X$ is a set of non-empty subsets of $X$ such that every element $x$ in $X$ is in exactly one of these subsets (*i.e.* $X$ is a disjoint union of the subsets).

**Definition 2.** A partition of the interval $[a,b]$ is a non-empty finite subset $P = \{x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ of elements of $[a,b]$, where $a=x_0<x_1<x_2<...<x_n=b$.

These definitions do not seem equivalent, and they are confusing to me. The elements of $P$ are not even subsets of $[a,b]$. Is there some form of inconsistency?

Comment: The term "partition" is a bit overused in math. You just have to get used to that. Further the answer of Kavi shows that there is a nice link between both.

Comment: @drhab, So, the notion of a partition of a set in Def.2 is predicated on another definition of a partition of a set ? If yes, what is that other definition of partition of a set that is used in Def.2 ?

Comment: For this see the comment of @Kavi on his own answer.

Comment: I don't think it answers the second part of my question in the comment above.

Comment: There are just two different concepts on an interval $[a,b]$ that both are labeled with "partition". It is evident how they are linked and am not capable of saying anything essential that is not mentioned yet.

Comment: I'm asking about the second notion of partition, how to make a partition of a general set -not necessarily an interval-, for example what is the partition of the set {1,2,3,4,5,6} using the second definition of a partition  ?  it's not obvious to me how to apply that notion on a set with discrete elements , not on an interval !

Comment: The second notion is only meant to be applied on intervals. Not on general sets.

Comment: I give an answer to this question in the context of a closely related question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812929/partition-of-an-interval-of-mathbbr/3995678#3995678

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are different notions. The best connection between these two is obtained by looking at the intervals $[x_{i-1},x_i)$. These form a partition of $[a,b )$ according to the first definition. You wiil have to ignore one of the end points to get a partition according to the first definition.

Comment: @yousefmagableh As I said in the answer these are different notions. Sometimes the same word is used for two different notions. I am just pointing out that these two notions are not completely unrelated. I have given you some connection between the two definitions of the word partition.

Comment: The key is to view the elements of $P$, which are also elements of $[a,b]$, as *bounds* of the intervals that partition $[a,b]$. Further discussions are available here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812929/partition-of-an-interval-of-mathbbr/3995678#3995678

Comment: Is it okay to leave an endpoint out like that though? What happens if I just ignore all the endpoints in a subintervals and partion into open subintervals, would the integration still hold?